# Define a parameter in R

Tags: r, matrix

hi guys i have this matrix :

```
m<-matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6*K,7,8,9,10,11,12),nrow=3,ncol=4)
```

but i can't define it because

```
K
```

is not a numeric argument.

I don't know how much will be the value of

```
K
```

so i want that

```
K
```

remain a parameter of that matrix.

For example i want solve a system of linear equation with this parameter K.

How can i do that?

Comment: put "6*as.numeric(K)" instead of "6*K"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it a `function`

```
m <- function(K) matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6*K,7,8,9,10,11,12),nrow=3,ncol=4)
```

which you can then use to solve an appropriate equation with `optim` or `optimize`.

Comment: if i want make the LU factorization of the matrix m  i can ??

Comment: it define a function .. when i call it i should always use a number...i want it should be a symbol ..

Comment: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4*x-1*y-1%2FL*z%3D%28q*%28L%5E2%29%29%2F4%2C+-1*x-2*y%2B2k%3D0%2C+y%2Bk%3D%28q*%28L%5E2%29%29%2C+x+%3D+-%28q*%28L%5E2%29%29%2F2+for+x%2Cy%2Ck%2Cz)

Comment: @user448381 It sounds like you want a symbolic computation system. You could have a look at the package `Ryacas`

Comment: look the link above, q and l are parameters and i didn't define any value for them...

Comment: yes James that is what i need.. can you make an example please?